# Can I integrate the Robot framework with AWS device farm? Does it support officially?

Tags: amazon-web-services, robotframework, aws-device-farm

Can I integrate the Robot framework with AWS device farm? Previously it's not supported as I can see.

Comment: What does "integrate with AWS device farm" mean to you? What do you want this integration to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use custom dependencies and frameworks (like Robot) when running mobile or desktop browser tests with AWS Device Farm. Please see our documentation here for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html